# How to pipe output from sub() to read.table() in R

Tags: r, pipeline

I am trying to read in a [csv from this website](http://www.informatics.jax.org/go/term/GO:0007049). Each line ends with `\t`, which causes `read.delim()` and `read.table()` to see the data lines as having 1 more column than the header line, which causes problems.

I can easily remove the `\t` from the end of the lines using this code:

```
file.set <- "data_source.txt"
temp <- file.set %>% 
    readLines() %>% 
    sub(" \\t$", "", .) %>% 
    writeLines()
```

What I cannot figure out is how to pipe the result of the `sub()` command to `read.delim()` without writing out a file using `writeLines()`. I have tried the following code:

```
temp <- file.set %>% 
    readLines() %>% 
    sub(" \\t$", "", .) %>% 
    read.delim(quote = NULL)
#  Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument

temp <- file.set %>% 
    readLines() %>% 
    sub(" \\t$", "", .) %>% 
    writeLines() %>% 
    read.delim(quote = NULL)
#  [prints info from file.set to console]
#  Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
#    'file' must be a character string or connection
```

The problem is likely that I do not understand how to use connections properly (or that using a connection is just the wrong way to do this). The tutorials that I have found on using connections in R refer mostly to getting data from remote databases, which makes me think I am doing it wrong.

Comment: I fixed the broken link to the data file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to write the data out after you've read it in. You can pipe that directly to the `text=` parameter of `read.delim`. For example

```
temp <- file.set %>% 
  readLines() %>% 
  sub(" \\t$", "", .) %>% 
  read.delim(text = .)
```

I can't open the actual file you used (The line doesn't work for me), but usually it would be easier just to read in the data with the extra column and then drop after import. It's not clear to me what the "problems" you were experience when reading the file in the first place actually were.

Comment: That was it! I hadn't noticed the `text` argument at the bottom of `?read.delim`. Regarding the initial error causing me to do these manipulations, it is ` Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :   duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed `. The ` \t` at the end of each line causes the data lines to have 1 more "column" than the header line. This causes `read.table()` to interpret the first "column" as the row names, which causes the above error. Thanks for your help.